# How to create an Ethereum side-chain aka pegged chain?

Tags: oracles, sidechain

With the ETH at an all time high and the gas price still at 20G Wei Ethereum transactions are becoming uneconomical.

We want to create an accounting system based on smart contracts which would simply cost too much to run on the Ethereum main net.

The solution we came up with is to create a new public Ethereum blockchain based on PoS and publish all the block hashes on the mainnet. This reduces the transaction count by an order of magnitude while ensuring that anyone can verify that we are not cheating.

Comment: Hi Dr Gorb. I'm going to flag this question as being too broad, I'm afraid. There are many ways to skin a cat, and your question would likely lead to more of a discussion, rather than a clear objective answer. You could have a look at the Raiden project to see how they've solved similar problems: http://raiden.network/

Comment: Could you please clarify what aspects of creating a "side-chain" or "pegged chain" you want input into, and what your specific challenge is?  I agree with Richard's comment that your question currently feels too broad, but I think it might work if you edited it to clarify the specific kind of design input you are seeking (and share what work / research you have already done around that, so you are not just outsourcing your homework to this group).  Right now, the body of your post is primarily focused on articulating your solution which could easily lend itself to an off-topic discussion.